# Adding quantity to a Commerce product's attribute

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a D7 Commerce Store. It will be selling to wholesales.

I have a Product that has multiple attributes. An example of the attributes is as follows;

T-Shirt Printing (Product)

- Size (S, M, L, XL, etc)
- Sides (1 Side, 2 Side)
- Service Type (All over, Spot)

How can I allow the customer to add that 1 product with multiple of a particular attribute?

Example; Customer should be able to order, 10 Small, 15 Medium, 20 Large of that one product "Tshirt Printing".

The Image below is an example from jakprints.com. I would like to do something similar. How can I replicate this in commerce? Or instead of using sliders... + or - buttons.

Please provide a few different ideas or POV's towards achieving this.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Commerce Add to Cart Extras](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_extras) module. It provides a new product reference field display formatter that does exactly what you need.

Comment: I use that module for two of my stores. It doesn't affect the actual attribute. It only allows for you to add a field via views so that you can add multiple & Quantities of those products. Unless i'm mistaken and haven't used it to its fullest potential.

Comment: Ahh, nope, you're right - I missed that you wanted them to be selecting other attributes before the size. Perhaps expanding on my answer, then, I'd suggest that maybe instead of using attributes for specifying sides and service type, I'd use line item fields for those instead. Since those are details pertaining to the fulfillment of the order and don't necessitate a different SKU, it would be safe to model those as line item fields so long as the pricing for those selections is standard across all products. You can use that field data in your product pricing rules as need be.